# Multiply / divide dataframe columns by list / series along axis 1

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with N columns, where N may be 0. And I have a list of scalar values, the same length than the list of columns in the dataframe. I want to multiply or divide the columns of the dataframe by the corresponding value in the list.

E.g.

```
Dataframe

    1  2  3
1   1  2  3
2   4  5  6
3   7  8  9

Multipliers

0 1 2

Expected

   1  2  3
1  0  2  6
2  0  5 12
3  0  8 18
```

Let's create data

```
# Empty
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({}, index=idx)
list_1 = []
series_1 = pd.Series(list_1, dtype=float)

# Not empty (1 element to shorten example)
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({1: [1]}, index=idx)
list_2 = [12]
series_2 = pd.Series(list_2, dtype=float)
```

It works as expected when I pass the multipliers as a list

```
df_2.mul(list_2)
    1
1  12
```

However, I get a warning if the list is empty

```
df_1.mul(list_1, axis=1)
<stdin>:1: FutureWarning: The default dtype for empty Series will be 'object' instead of 'float64' in a future version. Specify a dtype explicitly to silence this warning.
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [1]
```

So I tried to pass the list as a series. I don't get any warning when the series is empty

```
df_1.mul(series_1, axis=1)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [1]
```

But this is obviously not the right thing to do because when passing a series, the series index is matched with the column names.

```
df_2.mul(series_2)
    0   1
1 NaN NaN
```

I would like to rely on the columns order, like with the list.

How may I achieve this? I'm fine with the list. I just want to be future-proof, so I'd like to get rid of the warning.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one (hacky) way to do it:

```py
import pandas as pd

def helper(df, other, *args, **kwargs):
    if isinstance(other, list) and not other:
        return pd.DataFrame()
    return mul(df, other, **kwargs)


mul = pd.DataFrame.mul
pd.DataFrame.mul = helper


df_1 = pd.DataFrame({})
list_1 = []

df_2 = pd.DataFrame({1: [1]})
list_2 = [12]
```

Then:

```py
print(df_2.mul(list_2))

    1
0  12
```

```py
print(df_1.mul(list_1, axis=1))

# No warning
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

Comment: Sure. Ultimately I ended up adding a test as well. I was wondering if there was a built-in pandas way to do it? (Generally I'm happier when I find a pandas function doing things because it looks more efficient, although it is possible that pandas performs many such tests internally.)